# Eclipse Neon install failing on new Arch install

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

I recently installed Arch linux (technically antergos, but same thing). I also ended up installing the java jdk 7, 8, and 9. Eclipse is now constantly failing to start. I changed the config because it looks like it needs Java 8 and it's taking java 9. I also increased the threads to 20. I am now getting this error:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=13
/usr/lib/java-8-openjdk/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
It goes on
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
Goes on some more
-exitdate 128802
-vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/bin/java
Goes on about the garbage collector, required version, memory, max threads (20), updates, etc
```

If you need more I can send a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Alright. I needed to delete the java 9 folders and their contents, delete the default and default-jre links, and replace them with links that pointed to the Java 8 files. Eclipse now opens fine